# How to use active record to query a resource by it's root resource id?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have nested structure like

```
Resource A
-id

Resource B
-id
-a_id

Resource C
-id
-b_id

Resource D
-id
-c_id
```

Given an a_id I want to grab all the Ds in one query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM D
JOIN C on c_id
JOIN B on b_id
WHERE B.a_id = a_id
```

I know I could inline this SQL, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this with ActiveRecord relations?

Comment: are you asking for rails `includes` or `join` methods to eager load associations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
 hash_many :bs
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  has_many :cs
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :b
 has_many :ds
end

class D < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :c
end

C.joins(:c => :b).where(:b => {:a_id => <given_a_id>})
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the active_record docs.

```
D.joins(C: :B).where(B: { a_id: a_id})
```